# tslint error Use arrow function instead of function expression

Tags: ecmascript-6, tslint

i am having tslint warnings and i am new to es6 and still having some difficulty with its syntax.so I am not entirely sure how to convert this one in arrow functions.

[image]

and here is my code:

```
 let deletedQuestions = origQuestions.filter(function(obj) {
            return !updatedQuestions.some(function(obj2) {
                return obj.value == obj2.value;
            });
          });
          console.log(deletedQuestions);

          let addedQuestions = updatedQuestions.filter(function(obj) {
            return !origQuestions.some(function(obj2) {
                return obj.value == obj2.value;
            });
          });
```

Comment: Did you try using arrow function syntax? Please show us your attempt.

Comment: Hi @Bergi yes i have used it one of my function  this.state.qnaActionHistory.filter(items => items.action === "add").map( qna => qna.qnaItem); this one basically gets all the property qnaitem where the item action is add. but in my question above i am not sure how to perform and apply an if inside the filter and some

Comment: Yes, those look fine. What is the problem trying to use the same syntax for the `filter` and `some` arguments in the code in your question?

Comment: "*how to perform and apply an if*" - you don't need any `if` statement? Just return the same value that current function expressions do

Comment: hi, thanks got it to work now let deletedQuestions = origQuestions.filter( 
            obj => !updatedQuestions.some(obj2 => obj.value == obj2.value));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it would be

```js
let deletedQuestions = origQuestions.filter(obj =>
  !updatedQuestions.some(obj2 => obj.value == obj2.value)) console.log(deletedQuestions);
let addedQuestions = updatedQuestions.filter(obj =>
  !origQuestions.some(obj2 => obj.value == obj2.value))
```

Right?

Comment: ah yes right I finally got it to work using let deletedQuestions = origQuestions.filter( 
            obj => !updatedQuestions.some(obj2 => obj.value == obj2.value));

which is the same as yours! thank you